# Google Calendar unable to trace "child" events after "child" time update

Tags: google-calendar-api

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create an event that starts on Monday at 1pm and it repeats daily
2. Edit the event from that series that is scheduled for Wednesday and set it to start at 2pm and select to update This and following events

Once updated, events from Monday and Tuesday will have one `recurringEventId`, while Wednesday and following will have another `recurringEventId`.

Is there a way to track down events from Wednesday forward with the data like `recurringEventId`, or similar, I have from the event from Monday and Tuesday?

Hope that makes sense.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It sounds possible with the API, but can you provide more detail? The code you have so far for example.

Comment: @iansedano I do not see anything in the API that would provide such functionality. Can you point me in that direction? As for the code example, I have too much code to make a concise and understandable snippet. When you have one recurring event series they all have same recurringEventId. But when you update some event in that series and select to update `This and following` then it splits into two event series and there is no info about the original series in the newly created one.

Answer (score 0):

#### Flow of Calendar API with recurring events

For the sake of example say you have a calendar with no events.

You make a recurring event with 5 recurrences for 5 days in a row. It will create an event and if you call the `list` method with the API you will get one event:

```json
{
   "kind":"calendar#event",
   "id":"0000000011111111xxxxxxyyyyyy", // id is not real for this example
   "recurrence":[
      "RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=5"
   ]
}
```

There will be many other fields too, but I believe these are the relevant ones to your question.

If you take one of the 5 occurrences of that event and change its time, only for that event, then the `list` will return 2 events, the one previous, and:

```json
{
   "kind":"calendar#event",
   "id":"0000000011111111xxxxxxyyyyyy_20201202T150000Z", // note original ID with new date
   "recurringEventId":"0000000011111111xxxxxxyyyyyy", // note the original ID
   "originalStartTime":{
      "dateTime":"2020-12-02T16:00:00+01:00",
      "timeZone":"Europe/Madrid"
   }
}
```

- The original recurring event does *not* have a `recurringEventId`, it is only added if some events from the recurring event are modified to be a different date than the rest.
- If all you have is an event that may be a "original" recurring event, or a event that was originally part of a recurring event but had a time change, and you want to track down all events that are related via the original recurring event, you would need to:

  - If the event has a `recurringEventId` then you search for the event with that value in the field `id`, which would be the original recurring event and events with the same `recurringEventId`.

  **OR**

  - If the event has no `recurringEventId` it would be because it is the original current event. You should then search for all events that have this events `id` in their `recurringEventId`.

#### References

- [Events Overview](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events)
- [Events list method](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/list)